# How to reproduce a diagram, is there any package that does it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, asymptote

I would like to know if I can get some Help to reproduce the diagram below in beamer. Specifically, are there any great packages to do this sort of diagrams efficiently? thanks!

[image]

Comment: Using TikZ wouldn't be too hard (in case you haven't heard about it...) ■ Also it's advised that you include some descriptive description of the diagram as text, maybe "diamond diagram for the chain rule for multivariate function"

Comment: Or maybe `forest` package. e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370998/250119

Comment: The `pstricks`  package can easily do it – more specifically the `pst-node`  package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A plain TikZ solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2} \def\b{2.5}
\draw[cyan,thick,c/.style={fill=cyan,circle,inner sep=1.6pt}]
(-\a,0) node[c]{} node[black,left] (x) {$x$}--
(0,-\b) node[c]{} node[black,below] (t) {$t$} node[midway,black,below left]{$\dfrac{dx}{dt}$}--
(\a,0) node[c]{} node[black,right] (y) {$y$} node[midway,black,below right]{$\dfrac{dy}{dt}$}--                 
(0,\b) node[c]{} node[black,above,align=right] (w) {$w=f(x,y)$}
node[midway,black,above right]{$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}$}--cycle
node[midway,black,above left]{$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}$};
;
\path
(0,-\b-1) node{$\dfrac{dw}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$}
(\a+.6,0) node[right,align=left]{Intermediate\\variables}
(\a+.6,\b) node[right,align=left]{Dependent\\variable}
(\a+.6,-\b) node[right,align=left]{Independent\\variable}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** a plain Asymptote version

[image]

```
usepackage("amsmath");
unitsize(1cm);
real a=2, b=2.5;
pair M=(-a,0), N=(0,-b), P=(a,0), Q=(0,b);

draw(Label("$\dfrac{dx}{dt}$",Relative(.4),black),M--N,magenta+1pt);
draw(Label("$\dfrac{dy}{dt}$",Relative(.6),black),N--P,magenta+1pt);
draw(Label("$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}$",Relative(.6),black),Q--M,magenta+1pt);
draw(Label("$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}$",Relative(.4),black),P--Q,magenta+1pt);

for(pair p : new pair[] {M,N,P,Q})
fill(circle(p,.08),magenta);

label("$x$",M,W);
label("$t$",N,S);
label("$y$",P,E);
label("$z=f(x,y)$",Q,plain.N);

label("$\dfrac{dw}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$",(0,-b-1.2));
label(minipage("Intermediate variables",2.5cm),(a+.6,0),E);
label(minipage("Dependent variables",2.5cm),(a+.6,b),E);
label(minipage("Independent variables",2.5cm),(a+.6,-b),E);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: I hope you are not offended. When I see your picture I think of the movie Terminator :-) +1 for your answer. Using newtxtext,newtxmath the code is the almost the same.

Comment: @Sebastiano haha, some people have said me that ^^ I don't know about `newtxmath `

Comment: 

Comment: Please if possible, adding your `asymptote` code for your `asymptote` additional tag.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 Sure! in my free time

Comment: I have just add an Asymptote version of the figure

Answer (score 6):

I am not good at tikz, node atc. But I'v tried to help and here is my variant:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 
 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
 
\begin{document}
 
 \begin{minipage}[m]{0.5\linewidth}
 
\begin{flushleft}


\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\node[diamond,
font=\small,
line width=0.4mm,
scale=0.7,
    draw = cyan,   
    %text = red,
    minimum width = 7.5cm,
    minimum height = 9cm] (d) at (0,0) { };
      \node [above=0.5cm] (a) at (d.90) {$w = f(x,y)$};
      \node [above=0.5cm,right=0.1cm] (b) at (d.45) {$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}$};
      \node [above=0.5cm,left=0.1cm] (c) at (d.135) {$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}$};
      \node [left=0.1cm] (dd) at (d.180) {$x$};
      \node [right=0.1cm] (e) at (d.0) {$y$};
      \node [below=0.1cm] (f) at (d.270) {$t$};
      \node [below=0.9cm,right=-0.3cm] (g) at (d.-30) {$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}$};
      \node [below=0.5cm,left=0.1cm] (h) at (d.220) {$\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}$};
      \node at (d.90) [cyan,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt]{};
      \node at (d.180) [cyan,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt]{};
      \node at (d.0) [cyan,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt]{};
      \node at (d.270) [cyan,circle,fill,inner sep=3pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t} + 
\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}$
\end{flushleft}
 \end{minipage}
\hspace{-1.9cm}
 \begin{minipage}[m]{0.49\linewidth}
 \vspace{-1.2cm}
Dependent\\variable\\[3.0cm]
Intermediate\\variables\\[2.0cm]
Independent\\variable 
 \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good solution also for you +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Tikz package. This code can be a start point for you:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [nodePath/.style={circle,fill=yellow!40}]
  \node[nodePath] (n1) at (0,4)  {1};
  \node[nodePath] (n2) at (4,4)  {2};
  \node[nodePath] (n3) at (4,0)  {3};
  \node[nodePath] (n4) at (0,0)  {4};

  \foreach  \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3, n3/n4, n4/n1}
    \draw[->] (\from) -- (\to) node [midway, auto] () {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```